# Autoresponder capability in CiviCRM?

Tags: civimail, automation

Newbie here.  Checked previous posts on this and last answers over 6 years old.

Is there a way to set up an auto-responder series in CiviMail, e.g. when someone signs up for a newsletter on our website we can arrange for them to receive a series of 4 pre-set emails to "warm them up further" to what our organization is about?

If no feature within CiviCRM has anyone found a solution outside that complements well?

Thanks!

Comment: maybe reference the 'last answer' so we know what you looked at in case it is useful to others to update that answer too

Answer (score 2):

This type of thing can be achieved by using Scheduled Reminders or [CiviRules](https://docs.civicrm.org/civirules/en/latest/) (plus [Email API](https://civicrm.org/extensions/e-mail-api)) - the key is obviously the trigger for this. If you are wanting the trigger to be 'added to Group' then I believe CiviRules can do this, but Sch Reminders cannot.

Comment: Thanks petednz!  Will explore this path...

Comment: For the series of emails part, also have a look at https://civicrm.org/extensions/chass%C3%A9-supporter-journeys.  You can trigger that using CiviRules